# Vue table row-contextmenu event not firing?

Tags: vue.js, vue-events

I would like to open a custom context menu whenever the user clicks on a table cell in my vue page. So I'm trying to use the `row-contextmenu` event as defined [here](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#comp-ref-b-table-events), but it doesn't fire.

Table in the template:

```
<b-table @row-clicked="leftClicked" @row-contextmenu="rightClicked" border no-border-collapse striped :fields="fields" hover :items="items"></b-table>
```

Vue methods:

```
leftClicked() {
    alert("clicked");
},
rightClicked() {
    alert("right clicked")
}
```

The standard `row-clicked` event works fine and gets fired when i left-click on any row in the table. `row-dblclicked` also works fine. However, the `row-contextmenu` event doesn't even get fired to begin with and the standard browser context menu appears, even if i use `@row-contextmenu.prevent` (Chrome & Firefox). There are no errors in the console in both browsers.

The examples on [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table) and jsfiddles work fine in both browsers. So it seems to be a local problem?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my bootstrap-vue version was too old. I upgraded to 2.14.0 and everything is working fine.